# RDLC multiple column report with portrait Layout

Tags: .net, rdlc

Is there any way to  present the data in multi column rdlc report having portrait layout?

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a single click on the empty area of your rdlc designer form ,at the right side you will see some properties for the report find the propertie Columns, expand it and you see the number of how many columns you want to print. as for the portrait layout by default the page is set to portrait. but you can change it / check it if you want by right click on the report and select Report Properties.. and see the page setup and all the related options for the page.